# Excluding an element from jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a `.click()` event to work on a `div.content` except if clicked on something with a specific class, say, `.noclick`. Example html:

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="#" class="noclick">
</div>
```

Doing this doesn't work because the `<a>` tag is not technically in the selection:

```
$('.content').not('.noclick').click(function(){/*blah*/});
```

How can I get the click function to work if I click anywhere on `.content` except something with class `.noclick`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to exclude them from within the callback:

```
$('.content').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('noclick')) return;
});
```

Or stop the event from leaving those elements:

```
$('.noclick').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I would go with the second one. You can just drop it and your current code (minus the `.not()`) will work.

Comment: @CezaryWojcik: I'd go with the second one, personally. It looks nicer and does the same job.

Comment: I have additional conditions as well, so the first one sort of fits nicer with that. Thanks though.

Comment: Second one is safer because it will work if the `noclick` has nested elements that were clicked.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.content').click(function(event) {
   // ...
}).find('.noclick').click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.content').click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('.noclick')){
        // Handle click event
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.content').
on('click', '.noclick', function(){return false;}).
click(function(){alert("click")})
```

cancels clicks on '.noclick', yet fires clicks elsewhere

http://jsfiddle.net/FshCn/